Azure Frontdoor health probe DNS resolution when using PrivateLink
We are trying to set up Azure Frontdoor in front of AKS.
We would like to use HTTPS between frontdoor and AKS, and also use a private link.
We use cert-manager to handle the certificates in AKS. This setup will allow us to have a failover in case of another Frontdoor outage like the one that happened some weeks ago, by just changing some DNS records.
Attached is the current configuration for the Frontdoor Origin

We have to put test.example.com in the hostname because of certificate subject name validation.
And our DNS record for test.example.com looks like this:
test.example.com  CNAME wesfgsewdgdghy.z01.azurefd.net (azure frontdoor endpoint)
This works, but we are worried as we do not fully understand how Azure frontdoor will route the health probes and the traffic. We wonder how frontdoor will resolve test.example.com. Will it use a public DNS server? Will this cause a loop or trouble? Is this config correct?
Thanks!

The configuration you've implemented should work as intended, and the risk of DNS loops is less if the DNS setup is correctly.  In your case, the CNAME record for  test.example.com  points to  wesfgsewdgdghy.z01.azurefd.net, which is the Front Door endpoint. Azure Front Door will resolve the custom domain name using its own DNS servers, which are hosted on Azure. This will not cause a loop. Now when I say this, I assume that the DNS resolution always ends at the intended backend service. If your DNS records are set up to resolve to another Azure Front Door endpoint (which then resolves back to itself), a loop could indeed occur. Check this MS Doc
As for health probes, Azure Front Door uses its own health probes to check the health of the backend services. You can configure the health probe settings in the Azure Front Door Manager. Check this MS Doc
And regarding your private link query, checkout these two MS Doc and MS Doc
For further details, you can explore the Azure documentation on Azure Front Door health probes and Private Link setup.
